# What would be the time dilation standing on a neutron star in comparison to earth?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, spacetime, time, time-dilation

What would be the combined gravitational and velocity time dilation one would experience if they stood on the surface of a neutron star in comparison to standing on the earth's surface? Specifically, how many years on earth would pass for one day (24 hr period) on a neutron star?

I tried answering this question a number of years ago. I used formulas from the Wikipedia [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_dilation#Combined_effect_of_velocity_and_gravitational_time_dilation) on time dilation and some average data I could find on throughout the internet but I am skeptical of my answer.

I will post my answer, but first I am curious if anyone with specific training in this would give it a go so we can compare.

Thanks!!!

Comment: If the neutron star is spinning, you need to specify where you’re “standing” on it. At the equator?

Comment: @G.Smith fair point. The equator would probably be the best point from which to calculate

Comment: You would also need to give the rotational speed of the neutron star.